# Two different cosines are given and the value of the given expression is to be found...

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How do we go about solving the following problem?

If $cos(\theta-\alpha) = a$ and $cos(\theta-\beta) = b$ then what is the value of $sin^2(\alpha-\beta) +2abcos(\alpha-\beta)$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, a hint would be that $\alpha - \beta$ is just $-(\theta - \alpha) + \theta - \beta$, so you can use the cosine additive identities.

Comment: @rb612 I tried expanding the first two equations and then multiplying them together to get $ab = cos(\alpha-\beta) +sin\theta cos\theta[sin(\alpha + \beta)]$ and following your advice, I got $2cos(\alpha-\beta)cos(\alpha+\beta)=a+b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos\{(\theta-\beta)-(\theta-\alpha)\}$$

$$=ab+\sin(\theta-\alpha)\sin(\theta-\beta)$$

$$\{\cos(\alpha-\beta)-ab\}^2=\sin^2(\theta-\alpha)\sin^2(\theta-\beta) =\{1-\cos^2(\theta-\alpha)\}\{1-\cos^2(\theta-\beta)\}$$

$$\implies\{\cos(\alpha-\beta)-ab\}^2=(1-a^2)(1-b^2)$$

Can you complete it from here?